# Как можно выключить класс у элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Требуется удалить класс у элемента, но чтобы он удалялся на определённом разрешении экрана устройства. Понимаю, что возможно есть решение через `@media` в css, но не знаю как. Нужно что-бы из `<section class="container">` в `<section>`. Подойдёт любой вариант решения.

Comment: `но не знаю как.` Что вы пытались сделать и что не получилось? Что в [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media) у вас не получилось/не понятно? Решений много (через css. js) но если вы ничего даже не пытались сделать то создайте на бирже фриланса заказ и вам сделают

Answer (score 0):

"Подойдёт любой вариант решения."

Вам не нужно удалять этот класс. Вы действительно можете медиавыражением, при определённом разрешении экрана переопределить его сво-ва. Например:
Для десктопа св-ва css такие:

```
.container {
color: red;
}
```

а для планшета свойств этого класса нет:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: про медиа выражения с примера можно почитать тут: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Разве пустое значение .container{} в media выключить все свойства класса? Мне казалось что нет, поэтому и задал вопрос.

Comment: Во-первых, попробуйте. А во-вторых, какие задачи класс контейнер, решает у вас в коде? Где и как используется?

Comment: Попробовал, как и думал, не получилось. Решение проблемы нашёл сам.